# Wrapping fetch(), preserve promise-based API for outer function

Tags: javascript, react.js, promise

One of my react component's methods is using an async fetch() internally. After fetching the response from the server, it is being converted to JSON, then I perform a check on that JSON string. Finally, I return the result wrapped in a new promise. Here is the code:

```
fetchCalendarData(offset, length) {
    return fetch(this.props.Uri + '?offset=' + offset + '&length=' + length)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
        if (result.hasOwnProperty('redirect_to_login') && result.redirect_to_login == true) {
            window.location.reload(window.globalAppState.base_url + "/login");
        }
        return Promise.resolve(result);
    })
    .catch(() => {
        return Promise.reject('FAILURE');
    });
}
```

When I call the method, I do it like this:

```
this.fetchCalendarData(0, 6).then((fetched_calendar_data) => {
    this.calendar_data = fetched_calendar_data;
});
```

The code works, but I am not familiar with promise based flow at all, and those 3 return statements look a little weird to me. I also read about the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) but am not sure if that applies here. And, is it necessary to return the result wrapped in a new promise, at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but am not sure if that applies here. And, is it necessary to return
>   the result wrapped in a new promise, at all?

Yes, that applies here.

No, returning `Promise.resolve()` is not necessary. `.then()` returns a new `Promise` object. Use

`return result`

within the function passed to `.then()`.

Note, a value `return`ed from `.catch()` results in a resolved `Promise`. Depending on how errors are handled an error could be `throw`n (withing `{}` of a function).

```
this.fetchCalendarData(0, 6).then((fetched_calendar_data) => {
    this.calendar_data = fetched_calendar_data;
});
```

should include the second parameter to `.then()` to handle potential error

```
.then((fetched_calendar_data)=>{}, err=>{/* handle error */})
```

given then `Promise.reject()` is returned from `.catch()`, or `.catch()` should be chained to `.then()`

```
.then((fetched_calendar_data)=>{}
.catch(err=>{/* handle error */})
```

---

```
fetchCalendarData(offset, length) {
  return fetch(this.props.Uri + '?offset=' + offset + '&length=' + length)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty('redirect_to_login') 
       && result.redirect_to_login == true) {
         window.location.reload(window.globalAppState.base_url + "/login");
    }
    return result;
  })
  .catch(() => {
    throw new Error('FAILURE');
  });
}

this.fetchCalendarData(0, 6)
.then(fetched_calendar_data => {
  this.calendar_data = fetched_calendar_data;
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I really appreciate your comprehensive review! Is it just a matter of style if you use `.then(resolve_callback, reject_callback)` or `.then(resolve_callback).catch(reject_callback)` ?

Comment: @Benni There is a difference, see [When is .then(success, fail) considered an antipattern for promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289)